# how can I add CSS transition or animation, when the class toggling with JQ or JS?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I gonna add some transition or animation when my class toggling, for instance, on these below codes, I have a sidebar which I've added some animation to it, with CSS Animation library.
when sidebar opens, that I've toggle it with another class, animation working, but when it's closing, animation doesn't work anymore.

more detail about what I want:

1- I'm gonna when sidebar1 class being toggle with sidebar_menu, some animation or transition grow to apply on it, as I explained at the top, I mean when sidebar being closed animation or transition grow to apply on it

2- it's all right when the sidebar open, I just want when the sidebar get open via animation, being closed with animation, that's all
I'm sorry if I explained badly.
if it was any question please ask I'll answer

here a demo of what I made, that I think it shows my mean better
[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mohammadali0120/6nLjrhgc/1/)

here my JQ codes:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".response_menu_icon").click(function() {
      $(".sidebar1").toggleClass("sidebar_menu");
   });
   //
   $(".response_more_icon").click(function() {
      $(".area1").toggleClass("area_more");
   });
});
```

here my HTML codes:

```
<i data-feather="more-horizontal" class="response_more_icon"></i>
<!--  -->
<a href="" class="sidebar1 animate__animated animate__slideInRight">
     <div class="sidebar_right">
        <!--  -->
        <h4>Dashboard</h4>
        <a href=""><i data-feather="settings"></i><span>dashboard</span></a>
        <!--  -->
     </div>
</a>
```

and here my CSS codes:

```
.sidebar1 {
   display: none;
}
.sidebar_menu {
   // display: none;
   width: 250px;
   height: 100%;
   position: fixed;
   top: 80px;
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   flex-direction: column;
   text-align: center;
   background-color: #ffffff;
   -webkit-box-shadow: -2px 10px 8px 3px #eeeeee;
   -moz-box-shadow: -2px 10px 8px 3px #eeeeee;
   box-shadow: -2px 10px 8px 3px #eeeeee;
}
```

Comment: I can't find the exact animation library you are using but is there a slideOut or similar class?

Comment: @ale-plo  I've used of this library https://animate.style/

Comment: There is a class called slideOutRight that you can use!

Comment: Your class has the animation defined, when you remove it the animation also disappears. Keep the animation on the target both before and after of the click, and just change the direction of the animation with JavaScript with click.

Comment: @shamsadanam yes it disappears but how I can keep it to target?

Comment: @ale-plo I know but, how can I add to my tag? I mean we just can add an animation to our tag if I add another animation will mess with other animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I think you could do it. You check if the class is already applied and add the animation depending on this.

```
 feather.replace();
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".response_menu_icon").click(function() {
        if($(".sidebar1").hasClass("sidebar_menu")){
                $(".sidebar1").addClass("animate__slideOutRight");
           setTimeout(function(){$(".sidebar1").toggleClass("sidebar_menu");},200);
                      
         } else {
                $(".sidebar1").removeClass("animate__slideOutRight");
                $(".sidebar1").addClass("sidebar_menu");
            $(".sidebar1").addClass("animate__slideInRight");
       };
     //$(".sidebar1").addClass("animate__slideOutRight");
   });
   //
   $(".response_more_icon").click(function() {
      $(".area1").toggleClass("area_more");
   });
});
```

I use a set timeout to remove the class after the animation finishes playing.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your class with jQuery or JS and let your CSS handle your transition to the new position.

For example:

You have a sidebar that when on click of a button opens and then on click again closes.

The sidebar CSS would have the sidebars starting point (i.e. position). Then you could style the other class you are going to add to the ending position you wish for your element, etc.

```
 //starting position is hidden off the screen
#sidebar{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: -250px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: blue;
    transition: ease left .3s;
}

//brings the element into view when opened
#sidebar.toggled{
  left: 250px;
}
```

You can then add your classes as needed on a button click.

Here is an example [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HeroZero/x8cL0tbz/61/)

Another helpful resource when coding is at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/).  Here is a link to show some other uses for the [CSS Transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) property.